# Magento Fatal Error Class 'Zend_Cache' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I'm getting this error when I try to open the backend at my Magento shop:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 135

Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Check your disk usage and permissions.

Comment: i did, i have enough usage left. Which permissions exactly?

Comment: File ownership and permissions...

Answer (score 3):

If you use anything like APC / Redis of other sorts of cache be sure to really empty it correctly. this is most of the times the issue on this kinds of errors. You can empty it by download the apc.php you can download it from the packages here http://pecl.php.net/package/APC

Let me know if thats solves it.

Comment: thanks, i really don't have a clue how to install that...?

Comment: Is there a cache line in your local.xml?